# Javascript function returning undefined instead of number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have the following JavaScript function that's part of a larger script:

```
const sub = 'L';

export function getFeedData (sub) {
    var feedId;
    switch (sub) {
        case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case 'S':
            feedId = 1;
            break;
        case 'A': case 'C': case 'E':
            feedId = 26;
            break;
        case 'N': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'W':
            feedId = 16;
            break;
        case 'B': case 'D': case 'F': case 'M':
            feedId = 21;
            break;
        case 'L':
            feedId = 2;
            break;
        case 'G':
            feedId = 31;
            break;
    }
    if (feedId === 2) {
        var feed = require('./MockData');
    }
    return {
        feed: feed,
        feedId: feedId
    };
}
```

I've tested every other function in this script, and they're working properly. For this function, here's my test (I'm using Jest because this is part of a larger React app).

```
import React from 'react';
import {getFeedData} from '../mocks/apiMock';

it('returns 2 as the feedId when L is sub parameter for getFeedData', () => {
    expect(getFeedData.feedId).toBe(2);
});

it('outputs feed from getFeedData', () => {
    expect(getFeedData.feed).toBeDefined;
});
```

The latter of those tests is passing - not sure why that's happening.

The first one is what I'm more concerned about. It's returning undefined as getFeedData.feedId and therefore failing. I'm self-taught with JavaScript, and I'm sure that I'm making a silly mistake in that function, and that's why getFeedData.feedId is undefined. If someone could point out that silly mistake, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests are not calling the function, but attempting to access `feedId` property of the function object itself.

The second test passes, because indeed `getFeedData.feed` is `undefined`. But that doesn't mean this test case is correct. The intention is probably to call the function, with a parameter that has no mapping in the switch,
and then verify that its value is undefined.

```
it('returns 2 as the feedId when L is sub parameter for getFeedData', () => {
    expect(getFeedData("L").feedId).toBe(2);
});

it('outputs feed from getFeedData', () => {
    expect(getFeedData("?").feed).toBeDefined;
});
```

Comment: That does indeed fix my test results, thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately, I'm now not sure why the entire script has an unexpected output. I think I need to go practice my scopes and closures a bit. But that's a question for another time.